# apply functions in R for comparing columns

Tags: r, apply

I've a dataframe named `df`. I want to check, for each document, if the xcoordinate **and** ycoordinate are the same.

```
doc <- c("doc1", "doc2", "doc3") 
xcor <- c(3,4,5,3,4,5,3,4,4)   
ycor <- c(2,6,8,2,6,8,2,6,8) 
df <- data.frame(doc,xcor,ycor) 
df

doc xcor ycor  
doc1    3    2   
doc2    4    6  
doc3    5    8 
doc1    3    2  
doc2    4    6    
doc3    5    8  
doc1    3    2  
doc2    4    6  
doc3    4    8
```

I'm now struggling with all the apply functions, but this doesn't result in the desire outcome.
Which is

```
doc1 TRUE  
doc2 TRUE  
doc3 FALSE
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you need an `apply` function for this. We can count the number of repeat docs after eliminating duplicate rows:

```
table(df[!duplicated(df),]$doc) == 1

 doc1  doc2  doc3 
 TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Or even shorter (@DavidArenburg):

```
table(unique(df)$doc) == 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can still achieve it with `lapply`:

```
unlist(lapply(lapply(lapply(split(df, doc), unique), nrow), `==`, 1))
```

Looks kind of messy, but it works.